# Weight space for a finite-dimensional $\mathfrak{g}-$module $M$.

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, homological-algebra, homology-cohomology

Let $\mathfrak{g}$ a semisimple Lie algebra, $M$ finite-dimensional $\mathfrak{g}-$module, $\mu\in\mathfrak{h}^*_{\mathbb{Z}}$ and $s_i$ simple reflection such that $\langle\mu+\rho,\alpha_i^{\vee}\rangle\ge 0$. 
I want to determinate $H^p(\mathfrak{n},M)_{\mu}$.

Using Hochchild-Serre spectral sequence for the pair $(\mathfrak{n},\mathfrak{u}_i)$ I can proof that 
$$H^0(\mathfrak{n}/\mathfrak{u}_i,H^0(\mathfrak{u}_i,M))\simeq H^0{(\mathfrak{n},M)}$$
$$ H^0(\mathfrak{n}/\mathfrak{u}_i,H^1(\mathfrak{u}_i,M))\simeq H^1{(\mathfrak{n},M)}$$ 
and the other cohomology are zero.
What do I say anymore?

Comment: I'll want to say that $H^p(\mathfrak{n},M)_{\mu}\simeq H^{p+1}(\mathfrak{n},M)_{s_i*\mu}$, so I can proof Kostant's $\mathfrak{n}-$cohomology result.

Comment: You can proof to study $u_i$ like a natural $sl(2)$ representation, so you can use classic results to proof what you want.